# Any resources to understand Clamper circuit?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

Can anyone please provide some resources for understanding of Clamper Circuit, i'm having a hard time in understanding it when it comes to biased circuit.

[image]

Comment: What circuit are you talking about? Could you give us a link to a schematic?

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://electriciantraining.tpub.com/14181/img/14181_214_1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://electriciantraining.tpub.com/14181/css/14181_214.htm&h=192&w=368&sz=9&tbnid=RIYZxSfpexcAvM:&tbnh=65&tbnw=125&zoom=1&usg=__2DtCDpAgu95CUyRHHujxqMT9ptM=&docid=avi0P83r6UP7bM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ATrXUP3rAZDJrAeX-4GYDw&ved=0CEgQ9QEwAg&dur=3504

Comment: FYI, related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36765/diode-clamper-analysis

Comment: That's a Clipper circuit. When Input voltage exceeds 20v Battery reference, the Diode conducts, dropping the excess voltage through R1. Leaving Output peaks Clipped at ~20v.

Comment: @Optionparty, sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the source (represented by the circle with the diagram on the left in your schematic) tries to output more than +/- 20 V plus one diode drop, current will start to flow through the "clamper". When this happens, the "excess voltage" will drop across R1 and the output will only see ~20.7 V.

For example, say the source tries to generate +30 V. Then current will flow through D2. This current will also flow through R1, creating a voltage drop. The net result will be an output voltage of about 20.7 V (could be 20.2 V to 21 V, depending on the exact type of diode, value of R1, etc).

Aside: the elements drawn as batteries in your schematic should not generally literally be batteries. Something like Zener diodes is generally much more appropriate. If you did actually build this with batteries, the internal resistance of the battery would affect the clamp voltage, and I didn't account for this in my example above.